# Use Imagick and GD in Yii

Tags: yii, gd, imagick

I'm using Yii 1.1.6
I've coded a class that use GD and Imagick PHP extension. In mine, I declare a variable

```
class Myclass(){
    public function __construct()
    {
         $imagick = new Imagick();
    }
    // something more
}
```

I put my class into component folder.

In controller, as usual,

```
$image = new MyClass();
```

But yii notify me error 500: *include(Imagick.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory*.
I understand that means Yii doesn't recognize class and file Imagick in component folder?????

Any idea for my problem?
Please show me how to use Imagick and GD wright way in Yii.

P.s: I find out http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/image/, but, if I use that way, I'll rewrite my class, and it's just only used for Yii, I want to use my class for some projects.

UPDATE: Sorry about my foolish, I still work well on my Mac at home and my server but at office computer, I didn't config correctly for those extension.

Comment: Apparently you don't have the Imagick extension loaded in PHP. You should probably install it and make sure it is loaded.

Comment: @Danack thank you, I did config my xampp and it worked well again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't install php5-imagick package. You can read about it at [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.setup.php)

After installation you code will work perfectly.

On Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get install php5-imagick
sudo service apache2 reload
```

Answer (score 0):

You must add the ImageMagick setup path in main.php "config file"

here the sample for windows

```
'image'=>array(
        'class'=>'application.extensions.image.CImageComponent',
        // GD or ImageMagick
        'driver'=>'GD',
        // ImageMagick setup path
        'params'=>array('directory'=>'D:/Program Files/ImageMagick-6.4.8-Q16'),
    ),
```

for linux

```
'image'=>array(
        'class'=>'application.extensions.image.CImageComponent',
        // GD or ImageMagick
        'driver'=>'GD',
        // ImageMagick setup path
        'params' => array('directory' => '/usr/bin'),
    ),
```

use the flowing extension 
[image extension](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/image/)